# Handling multi-touch with corona/lua

Tags: events, lua, coronasdk, multi-touch

I am using multi-touch for a simple game. I have three buttons and if one button is pressed, the corresponding object is removed and if the correct two buttons are 'multitouched' then that corresponding object is removed. My problem is that the multitouch handler triggers two events, therefore removing two objects when it should only remove one. Here's a paraphrased version of my code:

```
function buttonHandler(event)

  -- Store the users input
   if (event.phase == "began") then
      mt[event.target.id] == true 
   end

   -- When the buttons are released, give the users input a value.
   if (event.phase == "ended") then
      if mt.One == true and mt.Two == true then number = 3
      elseif mt.One == true and mt.Two == false then number = 1
      elseif mt.One == false and mt.Two == true then number = 2
      elseif mt.One == false and mt.Two == false then number = 0
   end

   -- Compare the user input with the object and remove it if there's a match.
   if object.number == number then
      object:removeSelf()
      object = nil
   end

   -- Reset the user input.
   mt.One = false
   mt.Two = false
   mt.Three = false

end
```

What is happening is that if the user selects the number 3 by pressing both the 1 and 2 buttons, the comparison code is being triggered twice, once for each 'ended' phase. So if the the two objects on the screen are a 3 and a 1, then the three will be removed and for the 1, it acts as if the user guessed wrong. On the other hand, if there are two '3' objects on the screen, both objects will be removed with one 'guess'.

I thought about moving the comparison code outside of the function, but I would be in the same situation. There will still be two events fired for one guess.

(If my actual code is needed, I'd be more than happy to provide it. This just saves a lot of space. Also, if this is a basic answer and I just don't see it, a link to reading material would be greatly appreciated. I don't mind work, just don't know where to start.)

Comment: Have you tried saving the events + when they happened, then in your main loop / function ("tick" event?), handle them (then you know how many events there were, and you can act correspondingly).

Comment: Can you confirm that you have activated multi touch and that what you observe is on a physical device not on the corona simulator? Also keep in mind that we can't see your interface so you have to use clear simple example.  Unable to understand from your description what 1 2 and 3 refer to in relation to touches.